# Etymology of authoritarian DETAILED

Tags: etymology

How do I get beyond the [Etymonline etymology of authoritarian](https://www.etymonline.com/word/authoritarian) to see to first uses of the word in 1859 and 1862?

Comment: Thomas Lake Harris - 1858 - The Herald of Light - Vol.2 - Pag. 331
I am no authoritarian. 'Nature and reason' is my motto." Here Mr. May responded. "I feared this; but come; how do you know that Gloriana Perkins is your affinity ? https://books.google.it/books?id=DM0oAAAAYAAJ&pg=PA331&dq=%22authoritarian%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjj6Lm4-p3YAhUIEVAKHV1xCygQ6AEIJDAA#v=onepage&q=%22authoritarian%22&f=false

Comment: If you have access to the Oxford English Dictionary (the original at oed.com, not the many knock-offs also called "Oxford) they have extensive first-recorded-use information.

Comment: It's not particularly authoritative but google ngrams can help you find dated occurrences

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about resources.

Answer (score 2):

The [Oxford English Dictionary](http://www.oed.com/view/Entry/13344?redirectedFrom=authoritarian#eid) gives the following first recorded use of "authoritarian":

> 1856   A. J. Davis *Penetralia* 129   Does any one believe that the Book is essential to Salvation? Yes; there are many externalists and authoritarians who think so.